# Is user's consent towards a client relevant to the claims an api has access to?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

In the documentation of [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/consent.html) it says:

> [...] Consent is used to allow an end user to grant a client access to
>   resources (identity or API). This is typically only necessary for
>   third-party clients [...]

**Does this mean an api can get access to claims the user did not consent to for the client the user logged into?**

### TL;DR

If I login to my mvc-client giving consent to permit `Your email address`, I get what I expect:

- Secure-View of the mvc-client lists all claims from the identity token including the email address
- Calling API using user token also shows email address as expected

But if I login and on consent screen tick off the permission for `Your email address`:

- Secure-View of the mvc-client lists all claims from the identity token but not the email address (as expected)
- **But calling API using user token now also shows email address which I did not expect, or is this normal behavior?**

### Example-Configuration

I have this example (derived from the [QuickStart Example 5](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess)):

- mvc-client is from the sample
- `email`-Scope is listed in `Scope`-definition of that client's `OpenIdConnectOptions`
- `AllowedScopes` of that client include `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email`
- and the api `api1` accessible by the mvc-client has `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email` added to it inside `UserClaims`
- I am using a custom profile service, but this should not be relevant to the question (just checked, the mentioned QuickStart example behaves the same way if configured like the steps described above)

Answer (score 0):

*I am answering this myself, but not yet accepting, since I am not 100% sure.*

Yes, this is expected behavior, I think I just mixed up the different token types.
The api in my case is called `using user token` which effectively means `access token`.

*From my understanding identity resources mentioned in the quoted documentation part does not apply to the access token (user identity is modeled by the identity token), so the behavior should be expected.*